# How do i check if a file is a regular file?

Tags: c++, c, filesystems, dirent.h

How do i check in C++ if a file is a regular file (and is not a directory, a pipe, etc.)? I need a function isFile().

```
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *dirp;

while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
if ( isFile(dirp)) {
     cout << "IS A FILE!" << endl;
i++;
}
```

I've tried comparing dirp->d_type with (unsigned char)0x8, but it seems not portable through differents systems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call stat(2) on the file, and then use the S_ISREG macro on st_mode.

Something like (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3828537/6451573)):

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct stat sb;

if (stat(pathname, &sb) == 0 && S_ISREG(sb.st_mode))
{
    // file exists and it's a regular file
}
```

Answer (score 25):

You can use the portable [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) (The standard C++ library could not have done this up until recent introduction of [std::filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_regular_file) in C++17):

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::filesystem;

    path p("/bin/bash");
    if(is_regular_file(p)) {
        std::cout << "exists and is regular file" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

C++ itself doesn't deal with file systems, so there's no portable way in the language itself. Platform-specific examples are `stat` for *nix (as already noted by Martin v. Löwis) and `GetFileAttributes` for Windows.

Also, if you're not allergic to [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), there's fairly cross-platform `boost::filesystem`.

Answer (score 4):

In C++17, you may use std::filesystem::is_regular_file

```
#include <filesystem> // additional include

if(std::filesystem::is_regular_file(yourFilePathToCheck)) 
    ; //Do what you need to do
```

Note that earlier version of C++ may have had it under std::experimental::filesystem (Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_regular_file)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help, i've tried with

```
while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) { 
   if (!S_ISDIR(dirp->d_type)) { 
        ... 
        i++; 
   } 
}
```

And it works fine. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

bool isFile(std::string filepath)
{
    boost::filesystem::path p(filepath);
    if(boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(p)) {
        return true;
    }
    std::cout<<filepath<<" file does not exist and is not a regular file"<<std::endl;
    return false;
}
```