# Checking if a directory exists in Unix (system call)

Tags: c++, c, unix, directory, exists

I am not able to find a solution to my problem online.

I would like to call a function in Unix, pass in the path of a directory, and know if it exists. `opendir()` returns an error if a directory does not exist, but my goal is not to actually open, check the error, close it if no error, but rather just check if a file is a directory or not.

Is there any convenient way to do that please?

Comment: why did you write system call on the question? do you really want a system call, which will may only work on a single type of OS (linux, BSD, etc), or a POSIX function from the posix c headers (which will should work on any UNIX distro) will do?

Comment: If you look for more answers which don't rely on system calls, see [C++ - Determining if directory (not a file) exists in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980815/c-determining-if-directory-not-a-file-exists-in-linux)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

There are two relevant functions on POSIX systems: [stat() and lstat()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lstat.html).  These are used to find out whether a pathname refers to an actual object that you have permission to access, and if so, the data returned tells you what type of object it is.  The difference between `stat()` and `lstat()` is that if the name you give is a symbolic link, `stat()` follows the symbolic link (or links if they are chained together) and reports on the object at the end of the chain of links, whereas `lstat()` reports on the symbolic link itself.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct stat sb;

if (stat(pathname, &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode))
{
    ...it is a directory...
}
```

If the function indicates it was successful, you use the S_ISDIR() macro from [`<sys/stat.h>`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) to determine whether the file is actually a directory.

You can also check for other file types using other `S_IS*` macros:

- `S_ISDIR` — directory
- `S_ISREG` — regular file
- `S_ISCHR` — character device
- `S_ISBLK` — block device
- `S_ISFIFO` — FIFO
- `S_ISLNK` — symbolic link
- `S_ISSOCK` — socket

(Some systems provide a few other file types too; `S_ISDOOR` is available on Solaris, for example.)

Comment: `stat` expects pathname parameter to be a char?

Comment: Not a `char` but a `char *` — a string.  The links to the POSIX specification for the functions show that the first argument to `stat()` and `lstat()` is `const char * restrict pathname`.

Comment: check [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Testing-File-Type.html#Testing-File-Type) to see more information about the `S_IS*` macros

Comment: @m4l490n: From the POSIX specification for  `<sys/stat.h>`, as linked to in the answer.  It has definitions like: *`S_ISBLK(m)` — Test for a block special file.*

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of the [`stat`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/stat.html) system call by passing it the name of the directory as the first argument. If the directory exists a `0` is returned else `-1` is returned and errno will be set to `ENOENT`

EDIT:

If the return value is `0` you would need an additional check to ensure that the argument is actually a directory and not a file/symlink/char special file/blk special file/FIFO file. You can make use of the `st_mode` field of the [`stat structure`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really care about type of this filesystem object, access(name, F_OK) checks for exsistence of something with this name.
If you need to be sure this is directory, use stat() and check type with S_ISDIR() macro.

Comment: Note that if the real and effective UID are not the same (you're running a setuid program), then the `access()` system calls answers a different question from `stat()`.  Specifically, it checks whether the real UID (RUID) can access the file, whereas all the other system calls work with the effective UID (EUID) — including `opendir()`.

Comment: When using F_OK flag, access() actually doesn't check for access rights, it is only checks for file/dir/etc existence.

Comment: But even with `F_OK`, you can run into `EACCES` if the name passed to `access()` has multiple path components and the current process (EUID) does not have permission to search one of the leading directory components (so it checks the existence of a simple filename OK, but it may run into problems with a non-simple filename).

Comment: How? Why is nobody willing to just type out the POSIX syntax to get this done? Who cares how it is implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way would be:

```
int check(unsigned const char type) {
    if(type == DT_REG)
        return 1;
    if(type == DT_DIR)
        return 0;
    return -1;
}
```

You can then pass *struct dirent** object's d_type to *check* function.

If check returns 1, then that path points to regular file.

If check returns 0, then that path points to a directory.

Otherwise, it is neither a file or a directory (it can be a Block Device/Symbolic Link, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

C++17

Use `std::filesystem::is_directory`:

```
#include <filesystem>

void myFunc(const std::filesystem::path& directoryPath_c)
{
    if (std::filesystem::is_directory(directoryPath_c)) {
    //if (std::filesystem::exists(directoryPath_c)) { // An alternative*
        // do something.
    }
}
```

Or in its `noexept` version:

```
#include <filesystem>

void myFunc(const std::filesystem::path& directoryPath_c)
{
    std::error_code ec{};
    if (std::filesystem::is_directory(directoryPath_c, ec)) {
    //if (std::filesystem::exists(directoryPath_c, ec)) { // An alternative*
        // do something.
    }
}
```

- The disadvantage of the alternative is, that if `directoryPath_c` exists as a regular-file, `std::filesystem::exists(directoryPath_c)` returns `true` despite the folder does not exists.

Comment: There is also [`std::filesystem::exists()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists)

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you are right. The benefit I see in std::filesystem::is_directory() is that if a regular-file with the same name exists, the answer to "Is directory exists?" of std::filesystem::exists returns 'true'.