# Checking if a file is a directory or just a file

Tags: c, posix

I'm writing a program to check if something is a file or is a directory. Is there a better way to do it than this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>

int isFile(const char* name)
{
    DIR* directory = opendir(name);

    if(directory != NULL)
    {
     closedir(directory);
     return 0;
    }

    if(errno == ENOTDIR)
    {
     return 1;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char* file = "./testFile";
    const char* directory = "./";

    printf("Is %s a file? %s.\n", file,
     ((isFile(file) == 1) ? "Yes" : "No"));

    printf("Is %s a directory? %s.\n", directory,
     ((isFile(directory) == 0) ? "Yes" : "No"));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can call the [stat()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stat) function and use the `S_ISREG()` macro on the `st_mode` field of the [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) structure in order to determine if your path points to a regular file:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int is_regular_file(const char *path)
{
    struct stat path_stat;
    stat(path, &path_stat);
    return S_ISREG(path_stat.st_mode);
}
```

Note that there are other file types besides *regular* and *directory*, like devices, pipes, symbolic links, sockets, etc. You might want to take those into account.

Comment: When considering symlink cases, use lstat() instead of stat() as it does not follow the symlink.

Comment: There's at least a good discussion at [Checking if a directory exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828192/checking-if-a-directory-exists-in-unix-system-call/), where `stat()` and `lstat()` are discussed, and the complete set of POSIX file types is outlined.  I'm tempted to duplicate this question to that one.  The code should check the result of `stat()`, too, and handle errors appropriately.

Comment: @Jonathan, that answer is indeed more complete than mine, and was posted three months before mine, five years ago. And it's not like my own answer would disappear anyway. I see you wield Mjölnir in the `[c]` tag, so thank you for commenting before acting unilaterally. However, you're ultimately right. No worries, do what you have to do :)

Comment: this does not work on osx for me...

Comment: @vodish, maybe `stat()` is failing for you? What about the code in the duplicate, does it work for you?

Comment: This code is brittle: you should check that `stat` succeeds. Use `return !stat(path, &path_stat) && S_ISREG(path_stat.st_mode);`

Comment: @chqrlie is right, if the file does not exists for instance, the structure is not modified by the system call, and Valgrind reports that the jump depends on uninitialized value. It took me a while to figure out that random failure.

Answer (score 40):

Use the `S_ISDIR`macro:

```
int isDirectory(const char *path) {
   struct stat statbuf;
   if (stat(path, &statbuf) != 0)
       return 0;
   return S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to fill the `statbuf` struct with information.

Comment: This works fine as-is, stat function fills the info itself.

Comment: Ideally, the code would check that `stat` worked: `if (stat(path, &statbuf) != 0) return 0;` -- because a non-existent object is not a directory, and if you don't have permission to `stat()` it, it may as well not exist (even if the error reported is related to permissions).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are absolutely right, updated the code.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is better. Check the `stat` or the `fstat` function

Answer (score 3):

Normally you want to perform this check atomically with using the result, so [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) is useless. Instead, [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) the file read-only first and use [`fstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html). If it's a directory, you can then use [`fdopendir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopendir.html)
 to read it. Or you can try opening it for writing to begin with, and the open will fail if it's a directory. Some systems (POSIX 2008, Linux) also have an `O_DIRECTORY` extension to `open` which makes the call fail if the name is not a directory.

Your method with [`opendir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/opendir.html) is also good if you want a directory, but you should not close it afterwards; you should go ahead and use it.