# How to tell if FILE* is referring to a directory?

Tags: c, file-descriptor, stdio, fcntl, file-pointer

I just discovered that a `FILE*` can not only refer to a regular file, but also to a directory. If the latter is the case, `fread` will fail with `errno` set to `21 (Is a directory)`.

Minimal repro can be tested [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LWI0tKXua4UfIBCg)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    char const* sz = ".";

    int fd = open(sz, O_RDONLY | O_NOFOLLOW); // all cleanup omitted for brevity
    FILE* file = fdopen(fd, "rb");
    // I would like to test in this line if it is a directory

    char buffer[21];
    int const n = fread(buffer, 1, 20, file);
    if (0 < n) {
        buffer[n] = 0;
        printf(buffer);
    } else {
        printf("Error %d", errno); // 21 = Is a directory
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to detect early that my `FILE*` is referring to directory without trying to read from it?

**EDIT** to repel the duplicate flags:
I want to test on the `FILE*`, not the filename. Testing on filename only and then opening it later is a race condition.

Comment: Since you are already living in the POSIX-land, why not just use `fstat`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a file is a directory or just a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553012/checking-if-a-file-is-a-directory-or-just-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a POSIX-like environment, if you have just the file stream (`FILE *fp`), then you are probably reduced to using [`fileno()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fileno.html) and [`fstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html):

```
#include <sys/stat.h>


struct stat sb;
if (fstat(fileno(fp), &sb) != 0)
    …oops…
if (S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode))
    …it is a directory…
else
    …it is not a directory…
```

Comment: So I have to check one line earlier (on the file descriptor rather than the file stream). Just out of curiosity: Is there anything useful that can be done with a `FILE*` directory, or is it a design oversight that the `fdopen` succeeds in this case?

Comment: There are sound reasons to allow you to open a directory for reading — look at [`fchdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchdir.html), [`fstatat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstatat.html), [`fchmodat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchmodat.html), etc.  It isn't a design oversight.  Frankly, testing the result of the stream failing is pretty reliable, too.

Comment: I see that `open`ing a directory makes sense. But should why should we be able to `fdopen` it?

Comment: Because it is a valid file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on a POSIX-based system, use `stat()` (if you wish to use the filename in `sz` before the call to `open()`) or `fstat()` (if you wish to use the descriptor `fd` after calling `open()`) to get a file status structure from the OS.  The member of the structure named `st_mode` can be used with the POSIX API `S_ISDIR(st_mode)` to see if the file is a directory.

For more information, see: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html

Comment: `stat` or `fstat`?

Comment: `fstat`, not `stat`. Need not be unix; anything POSIX-conforming or close. And avoid linking to that site for man pages. It's SEO spam and has outdated files. Use the canonical site, man7.org

Comment: `stat()` when you have a filename, `fstat()` when you have a file descriptor.

Comment: @JohnH: OP's question is about having a `FILE*`, which which you can obtain a fd via `fileno`. There is no way to obtain a filename from that, and one need not even exist.

Comment: fine.  I was interpreting the check to be done using `sz` before the `open()` but if doing it after, sure, use fstat().

Answer (score 0):

Checking The fcntl.h [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/fcntl.h.0p.html) page:

> header shall define the following symbolic constants as
>   file creation flags for use in the oflag value to open() and
>   openat().  The values shall be bitwise-distinct and shall be suitable
>   for use in #if preprocessing directives.

And the flag :

> O_DIRECTORY Fail if not a directory.