# Check if object at a path is a file or directory cross platform?

Tags: c, filesystems, cross-platform

You can use the [`stat()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stat) function to check if an object is a file or directory, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553076/13783520). My issue is, `<sys/stat.h>` isn't on Windows, and I'm not sure what the Windows equivalent or Windows function is. This question is how do I do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3828192/13783520), but specifically in a cross platform manner.

While avoiding conditionally compiled code, how can I cross platform check if an object at a path is a file or a directory in C? Although there's an [almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62312279/is-there-a-cross-platform-way-to-check-if-an-object-specified-in-a-path-is-a-dir),  it cannot help me as it's unanswered, and the author is deleted so the question cannot be maintained.

To my understanding `fopen()` is cross platform, and so is `opendir()`, `readdir()`, `scandir()` etc, so why wouldn't simply checking if an object is a file or directory be cross plaform? If there is no way, and conditionally compiled code is the only way, how do I do it in Windows?

Comment: There's no way in standard C. Conditional compilation of however it's done on Windows and `stat()` on other OSes is probably going to cover 99%+ of (non-embedded)  uses though.

Comment: @Shawn Well how is it done on Windows?

Comment: Beats me; I don't do a lot of Windows programming.

Comment: [`GetFileAttributes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesa) and [`GetFileType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfiletype) seem to be the relevant functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately in C there is not an easy, portable or direct way to do this.

To that though, here's a bit of C code I converted from some C++ code I wrote for a cross platform library that can be used to check if a file or directory exists:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#if defined(OS_WIN)
    #include <windows.h>
#else
    #include <dirent.h> // for *Nix directory access
    #include <unistd.h>
#endif

bool file_exists(const char* file)
{
    if (file == NULL) { return false; }
    #if defined(OS_WIN)
        #if defined(WIN_API)
            // if you want the WinAPI, versus CRT
            if (strnlen(file, MAX_PATH+1) > MAX_PATH) {
                // ... throw error here or ...
                return false;
            }
            DWORD res = GetFileAttributesA(file);
            return (res != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES &&
                !(res & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY));
        #else
            // Use Win CRT
            struct stat fi;
            if (_stat(file, &fi) == 0) {
                #if defined(S_ISSOCK)
                    // sockets come back as a 'file' on some systems
                    // so make sure it's not a socket or directory
                    // (in other words, make sure it's an actual file)
                    return !(S_ISDIR(fi.st_mode)) &&
                        !(S_ISSOCK(fi.st_mode));
                #else
                    return !(S_ISDIR(fi.st_mode));
                #endif
            }
            return false;
        #endif
    #else
        struct stat fi;
        if (stat(file, &fi) == 0) {
            #if defined(S_ISSOCK)
                return !(S_ISDIR(fi.st_mode)) &&
                    !(S_ISSOCK(fi.st_mode));
            #else
                return !(S_ISDIR(fi.st_mode));
            #endif
        }
        return false;
    #endif
}

bool dir_exists(const char* folder)
{
    if (folder == NULL) { return false; }
    #if defined(OS_WIN)
        #if defined(WIN_API)
            // if you want the WinAPI, versus CRT
            if (strnlen(folder, MAX_PATH+1) > MAX_PATH) {
                // ... throw error here or ...
                return false;
            }
            DWORD res = GetFileAttributesA(folder);
            return (res != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES &&
                (res & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY));
        #else
            struct stat fi;
            if (_stat(folder, &fi) == 0) {
                return (S_ISDIR(fi.st_mode));
            }
            return false;    
        #endif
    #else
        struct stat fi;
        if (stat(folder, &fi) == 0) {
            return (S_ISDIR(fi.st_mode));
        }
        return false;
    #endif
}
```

To build it for Windows, simply define `OS_WIN` for that build; additionally, if you want to stick with full WinAPI, versus using the Windows CRT, you can define `WIN_API`.

To check if the given path is a file or directory, you can use something like the following code:

```
bool is_file(const char* path)
{
    return file_exists(path) && !dir_exists(path);
}

bool is_dir(const char* path)
{
    return dir_exists(path) && !file_exists(path);
}
```

You can obviously change the code to whatever suits your needs, but that should get you in the direction you need to build your code on Windows/macOS/*nix systems.

I hope that can help.

Comment: What is and why do I need `#include <fcntl.h>`? Could you please clarify that?

Comment: @user13783520 .. sorry, `fcntl.h` includes other functions for I/O control .. you don't need it for this specific code; modified answer to reflect that.