# Is there a programmatic way to tell if a symlink points to a file or directory in C?

Tags: c, posix, symlink

I am iterating directories recursively with `readdir`.

`struct dirent` is documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Directory-Entries.html), and notes that `d_type` can have different values including `DT_LNK` and `DT_DIR` and `DT_REG`.
However, when `d_type` is `DT_LNK`, there is no hint about whether the link is to a file or directory.

**Is there a a way to check whether the target of a symlink is a file or directory?**

Comment: The directory information for a symbolic link cannot indicate whether the target is a file or directory because the target can change at any moment. E.g., if the link `foo` points to the file `/mnt/directory/bar`, another process could remove the file `/mnt/directory/bar` and create a new directory `/mnt/directory/bar`, and nothing in the symbolic link, its metadata, or its directory would change. To know what a symbolic link points to, you must examine its target.

Comment: I think my question might be better framed as "how might I examine the target in a way that tells me whether it's a file or directory?" 
Or maybe, how do I map from a `dirent` to a data structure that tells me whether it's a file or directory?

Comment: I'd guess you have to follow the path

Comment: @Axeltherabbit Can you be more concrete? What system call should I be using?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `readlink()`. However, I don't see anything in the `man 2 stat` page that says whether it's a file or directory.

Comment: You don't have to call `readlink` at all -- just call `stat` on the path of the symlink; it will be followed.

Comment: Ah I found it, thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553076/391161

Comment: @merlin2011: remember that you must construct the path from the name of the directory and the entry name to pass to `stat`.

Comment: Yup, I know. Thanks for reminder though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dirent` structure might tell you if the entry is a directory or a symbolic link, but some file systems do not provide this information in `d_type` and set it to `DT_UNKNOWN`.

In any case, the simplest way to tell if a symbolic link points to a directory or not, is via a `stat` system call that will resolve the symbolic link and if successful, will populate the `stat` structure, allowing for `S_ISDIR` to give you the information:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int is_directory(const char *path) {
    struct stat st;
    return !stat(path, &st) && S_ISDIR(st.st_mode);
}
```

Note these caveats:

- you must construct the path from the directory name and the entry name to pass to `is_directory()`.
- recursing on directories linked to by symbolic links may cause infinite recursion as the symbolic link may point to a parent directory or the directory itself where it is located.

Comment: You can use `dirfd` on the `DIR *` to get the fd for the directory and use that with the `d_*` path from the dirent and pass to `fstatat`