# C++ - Determining if directory (not a file) exists in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, directory, exists

How would I determine if a directory (not a file) existed using C++ in Linux? I tried using the stat() function but it returned positive when a file was found. I only want to find if the inputted string is a directory, not something else.

Comment: `stat()` should work. How were you using it?

Comment: struct stat st; cout << stat(input,&st) << endl; if(stat(input,&st) != 0) { ... } - Both directory and file returns 0 when cout-ed.

Comment: Imho the duplication flag is incorrect, since the other question is about searching for a system call, while this question is about general ways in C++.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to [man(2) stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) you can use the S_ISDIR macro on the st_mode field:

```
bool isdir = S_ISDIR(st.st_mode);
```

Side note, I would recommend using Boost and/or Qt4 to make cross-platform support easier if your software can be viable on other OSs.

Comment: After #including <sys/types.h>, <sys/stat.h> and <unistd.h> I get the compiler error, g++ reports "error: ‘S_IDDIR’ was not declared in this scope".  Anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Bahah.  Typo.  S_IDDIR -> S_ISDIR.

Answer (score 21):

how about something i found [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/584434-check-directory-exists-c)

```
#include <dirent.h>

bool DirectoryExists( const char* pzPath )
{
    if ( pzPath == NULL) return false;

    DIR *pDir;
    bool bExists = false;

    pDir = opendir (pzPath);

    if (pDir != NULL)
    {
        bExists = true;    
        (void) closedir (pDir);
    }

    return bExists;
}
```

Or using stat

```
struct stat st;
if(stat("/tmp",&st) == 0)
    if(st.st_mode & S_IFDIR != 0)
        printf(" /tmp is present\n");
```

Comment: It may not be that bad but the example given above is not really that efficient and the bottom example is what I am using already, except that I am using != instead of ==

Comment: ya the bottom one needs to be updated with DarkDust's extra `and` condition. `(myStat.st_mode) & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR)`. thanks DarkDust.

Comment: The example given above is the only one working for me so I am going to accept it as the answer for now.

Comment: It is not necessary to try opendir on the directory; use the S_ISDIR macro.

Comment: Are you saying that if the dir exists it should be if(st.st_mode & S_IFDIR == 0)  ???

Answer (score 10):

If you can check out the [boost filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm). It's a great way to deal with this kind of problems in a generic and portable manner.

In this case it would suffice to use:

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"   
using namespace boost::filesystem; 
...
if ( !exists( "test/mydir" ) ) {bla bla}
```

Comment: fatal error: boost/filesystem.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: Well, you need to download and install boost... But I doubt you'll regret that :)

Comment: Still not working after install, "namespace ‘boost::filesystem’ not allowed in using-declaration" :/

Comment: Sorry, corrected the answer...

Comment: why is boost the path to darkness?

Answer (score 7):

The way I understand your question is this: you have a path, say, `/foo/bar/baz` (baz is a file) and you want to know whether `/foo/bar` exists. If so, the solution looks something like this (untested):

```
char *myDir = dirname(myPath);
struct stat myStat;
if ((stat(myDir, &myStat) == 0) && (((myStat.st_mode) & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR)) {
    // myDir exists and is a directory.
}
```

Comment: No, what I mean is "/foo/bar/baz" and "/foo/bar/baz" use the same would be considered as the same string but one baz is a directory and another is a file. Using stat() it only tells me if the string exists, not if it's a file or directory.

Comment: How could that ever happen? You can't have two different directory entries with the same name; either `/foo/bar/baz` doesn't exist, or it exists and is a directory, or it exists and is not a directory; it can't exist as *both* a directory and not a directory.

Comment: Ah, so you want to know which it is. In that case, OneOfOne's answer is what you want.

Comment: This is also a correct answer except that the use of `st_mode & S_IFMT` instead of `S_ISDIR` is poor style.

Comment: @MetaDark: stat *does* tell you whether the path is a directory, in the `st_mode` flags. Either use my code to check for the directory flag or the `S_ISDIR` macro, as seen in the answer of OneOfOne.

Comment: I love c++, this is intuitive and so easy to remember and it works!

Answer (score 4):

In C++17**, [`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) provides two variants to determine the existence of a path:

1. [`is_directory()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_directory) determines, if a path is a directory and does exist in the actual filesystem
2. [`exists()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists) just determines, if the path exists in the actual filesystem (not checking, if it is a directory)

Example (without error handling):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem> // C++17
//#include <experimental/filesystem> // C++14
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
//namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem; // C++14

int main()
{
    // Prepare.
    const auto processWorkingDir = fs::current_path();
    const auto existingDir = processWorkingDir / "existing/directory"; // Should exist in file system.
    const auto notExistingDir = processWorkingDir / "fake/path";
    const auto file = processWorkingDir / "file.ext"; // Should exist in file system.

    // Test.
    std::cout
        << "existing dir:\t" << fs::is_directory(existingDir) << "\n"
        << "fake dir:\t" << fs::is_directory(notExistingDir) << "\n"
        << "existing file:\t" << fs::is_directory(file) << "\n\n";

    std::cout
        << "existing dir:\t" << fs::exists(existingDir) << "\n"
        << "fake dir:\t" << fs::exists(notExistingDir) << "\n"
        << "existing file:\t" << fs::exists(file);
}
```

Possible output:

```
existing dir:   1
fake dir:       0
existing file:  0

existing dir:   1
fake dir:       0
existing file:  1
```

**in C++14 [`std::experimental::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) is available

---

Both functions throw [`filesystem_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/filesystem_error) in case of errors. If you want to avoid catching exceptions, use the overloaded variants with [`std::error_code`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code) as second parameter.

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

bool isExistingDir(const fs::path& p) noexcept
{
    try
    {
        return fs::is_directory(p);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        // Output the error message.
        const auto theError = std::string{ e.what() };
        std::cerr << theError;

        return false;
    }
}

bool isExistingDirEC(const fs::path& p) noexcept
{
    std::error_code ec;
    const auto isDir = fs::is_directory(p, ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        // Output the error message.
        const auto theError = ec.message();
        std::cerr << theError;

        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return isDir;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const auto notExistingPath = fs::path{ "\xa0\xa1" };
    isExistingDir(notExistingPath);
    isExistingDirEC(notExistingPath);
}
```

Comment: Why use `is_directory()` first and then `exists()` second? Also, is `exists()` really needed?

Comment: On Windows, I did: `if (!is_directory("myDir")) { create_directory("myDir"); if (!is_directory("myDir")) { return false; } }` and it worked just fine (created the folder if it didn't exist, didn't if it did exist as a folder, returned false if it existed as a file).

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the hint, `exists()` was redundant indeed! I've updated the example. Since the question does not include creating the directory, I'm omitting that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out whether a directory exists because you want to do something with it if it does (create a file/directory inside, scan its contents, etc) you should just go ahead and do whatever you want to do, then check whether it failed, and if so, report `strerror(errno)` to the user.  This is a general principle of programming under Unix: don't try to figure out whether the thing you want to do will work.  Attempt it, then see if it failed.

If you want to behave specially if whatever-it-was failed because a directory didn't exist (for instance, if you want to create a file and all necessary containing directories) you check for `errno == ENOENT` after `open` fails.

I see that one responder has recommended the use of `boost::filesystem`.  I would *like* to endorse this recommendation, but sadly I cannot, because `boost::filesystem` is not header-only, and all of Boost's non-header-only modules have a horrible track record of causing mysterious breakage if you upgrade the shared library without recompiling the app, or even if you just didn't manage to compile your app with *exactly* the same flags used to compile the shared library.  The maintenance grief is just not worth it.

Comment: If it detects it as it file, it continues anyway and creates a seemingly corrupt tar file. Oh yeah if I haven't said it already I am trying to tar the directory.

Comment: The first step in creating an archive from a directory is scanning the directory, so why can't you just call `opendir` and see if it fails (which it should when applied to a plain file)?