# How do I check if file name is a directory or not in C?

Tags: c, directory, directory-structure

I'm using `if(strstr(dir->d_name, ".") == NULL && strstr(dir->d_name, "..")`to check if its a directory/subdirectory, but this is still printing out some files that are not directories...Im using the direct struct and DIR.

Comment: Can you show a bit more code?

Comment: Depending on operating system, if you read [the `readdir` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) you will see that it have a member called `d_type` which is the type of "file" the directory entry is.

Comment: See [Checking if a directory exists in Unix system call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828192/checking-if-a-directory-exists-in-unix-system-call) for the answer when not working with `readdir()` et al, or when your system provides only the minimal information that the POSIX specification for `struct dirent` from [`<dirent.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/dirent.h.html) defines (which is `d_name` and `d_ino`). More accommodating systems may provide the file type in extended information that is stored directly in the `struct dirent` structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strstr` searches for a substring inside another string, so it will return a match for every *name* that contains a single (well, or a double) period.

You probably meant to use `strcmp`:

```
if (strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") && strcmp(dir->d_name, ".."))
   .. not one of the default root folders ..
```

Before or after this, you can check if it is a folder or not:

```
if (dir->d_type == DT_DIR)
  ..
```

or use `stat`. (Note that `d_type` may not be supported by certain file system types.)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like stat() and fstat(). You then look at the st_mode field of the output with macros like S_ISDIR(m).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, you can use [`getdents`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) which include entry type. Otherwise you'll probably have to use [`stat`/`lstat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) to get type info for every item.