# Problem trying to copy string char by char

Tags: c, string, unix, char, filesystems

I'm trying to travel a char array char by char and copy it into another char array until the read character is \ because I want to create the directories of the adress if not created or access if they are created.

For example:

```
Adress: dir2/dir3/a
```

My algorithm:

```
path = dir2
//if dir2 not created make dir2 and change actual directory to dir2
//if created then access dir2 changing the actual directory to dir2
//empty path with memset and keep storing the adress
path = dir3
//repeat...
```

But when I try to access path I get the last character and not all the path string

Output:

```
path0: d
path1: i //Should be di
path2: r //Should be dir
path3: 2 //Should be dir2
path: 2 //Should be dir2
```

I don't know if there is a more efficient way to do this and I don't know how to get the complete path string and not the last character, I was inserting '\0' at the end just in case it was some problem with the string end character

name and path are a char[256] variable
Code:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++) 
        {
            if(name[i] != '/')
            {
                path[j] = name[i];
                path[i+1] = '\0';
                printf("path%d: %s\n", i,path);
            }
            else
            {
                path[i] = '\0';
                printf("path: %s\n", path);
                n = chdir(path);
                if(n == ENOENT)
                {
                    n = mkdir(path, 0777);
                    if (n != 0) 
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to make the directory to extract: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                        close(fmypack);
                        return E_DIR1;
                    }
                    chdir(path);
                }
                else if(n == EACCES)
                {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to access the directory: %s, %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
                        close(fmypack);
                        return E_DIR2;
                }
                else if(n != 0)
                {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Unknow error when try to access the directory: %s, %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
                        close(fmypack);
                        return E_DESCO;
                }
                memset(path, 0, sizeof path);
                j=0;
            }
```

Comment: Don't do `chdir()` — `mkdir()` will take a path quite happily referring to a subdirectory.

Comment: The `printf("path%d: %s\n", i,path);` after each character is *undefined behaviour* without a string terminator (as done just below in `else`).

Comment: @WeatherVane: He could have a `memset()` above the `for` loop.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yep but I'm doing this to control if the directory is already created or not

Comment: Where and how are `name` and `path` and `j` initialized? Post complete code.

Comment: @SGeorgiades     char name[256]; int i, j = 0;
                             char path[256];

Comment: Also, it seems to me that this task would be much easier using `strtok`

Comment: `j` is not incremented in the code you've shown... which is why `path` is only ever a single character

Comment: @SGeorgiades you're right :(

Comment: If you do it right, you should be fine.  You can find out whether a file name represents a directory with [`stat()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3828537/15168).  You can create a string containing `"dir2"` and create that directory if it doesn't exist.  Then you can extend that string to `"dir2/dir3"` and create that directory if it doesn't exist.  Rinse and repeat until you reach the end of the path.  See also [How can I create a directory tree in C++/Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/675193/15168) (but that answer is C code that can be called from C++).

Comment: In general, if your program uses `chdir()`, you have to be careful because if the user specifies file names relative the current directory when the program is invoked but you change directory elsewhere, you have a lot of work to do to make sure you still access the correct files.  Note `fchdir()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it.

```
                path[i] = '\0';
```

But path is built up using `j` as an indexer.

```
                path[j] = '\0';
```

Should be correct.

And you're missing your increment on `j`:

```
                path[j] = name[i];
                path[i+1] = '\0';
```

Should be:

```
                path[j++] = name[i];
                path[j+1] = '\0';
```

What's funny is it actually *is* faster to do this one component at a time with `chdir()`, but the probability that you have found this is remote. When you get a couple hundred directories deep you can measure it.

Comment: Yep i knew that but I wanted to control if a directory of the path is already created or not idk if I can have that information in a simple way with chdir()

Comment: I have another question, how can I access the flag errors of chdir()? If I check n is always -1 if a problem occurs, how can I check if a EACCES error occurs?

Comment: @JamesR: `errno`