# Recognize file type in C++

Tags: c++

I implemented a solution to the problem meant to be cross-platform and adherent to the C++ standard library.

```
bool isdir(const char *string) {
   ofstream file(string, ios::out);
   return file.fail();
}
```

Yet, if the file is actually writable, the program opens an empty file with `string` name in its working directory.
How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You should probably implement this using OS specific functions. You could open it as read-only, but that's not going to work either. If the path is a file which has no read permissions, your algorithm will indicate that it is a directory.

Comment: Thank you for exposing a problem I did not think of. Anyway, I am looking for a standard function, though.

Comment: @Stencil There is none. The C++ standard doesn’t know about the file system.

Comment: If you want portability, boost::filesystem would probably be best.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/328958/809387

Comment: So Boost implements platform specific functions (conditionally compiled depending on the platform)?

Comment: Note that `file` will _never_ be `NULL`. You can check if the file is open with [`is_open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/is_open).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i check if a file is a regular file in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328944/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-is-a-regular-file-in-c)

Comment: It is not a duplicate because I asked how to prevent ofstream constructor from creating a file in case it does not exist.

Comment: @Stencil: Maybe, but first of all you asked: "Recognize file type in C++". It is in the title.

Comment: Yeah, it is the title itself, which synthetizes the question. I'm grateful to you for having considered my question, and your answer is useful anyway; in fact I upvoted it, but it didn't fully satisfied what I was asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard way of detecting if a file is a directory in C++. But you can use [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm). It is well portable.

**Edit:** It seems that this question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/328958/426288).